# How can I dual boot ubuntu alongisde windows 7's GUID GPT partition?

Tags: dual-boot

I have windows 7 SP1 installed on my machine that uses guid gpt partition instead of the old MBR. When I try dual booting ubuntu with it, Ubuntu doesn't recognize the operating system - basically it sees all of my hdd space as unallocated.

How can I dual boot ubuntu with windows 7 keeping the guid gpt partition ?

Comment: It sounds like you have a corrupt partition table.  Please edit your question to show the output of `sudo fdisk -lu` and `sudo parted print`

Answer (score 1):

I would install Ubuntu to a gpt partition, as well. That is, in fact, what I do, but I do not run Windows on my PC, so I cannot give you a specific how-to-do-it answer.

You can find tons of valuable info at this web site, though:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/index.html

Another great resource is the Parted Magic LiveCD, which includes the gdisk gpt partitioning program.

Good luck!